# Set Limit for Multiselect dropdown

Tags: vtiger

How to set limit in multiselect option dropdown in vtiger code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to destroy and register [select2](https://select2.org/selections) libraries again for your input after page loaded.

use something like the following code and set your desired value via maximumSelectionLength params

```
$('#selectinput').select2('destroy');
var select2params = {maximumSelectionLength: 2, tags: [], tokenSeparators: [","]}
app.showSelect2ElementView($('#selectinput'), select2params);
```